# How to stop Source.tick in the Actor?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I have an Actor, that produces every 2 seconds a `NotUsed`. Maybe it does not make any sense, but it is only for testing purpose.

```
import akka.NotUsed
import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorLogging, Props}
import akka.stream.{ActorMaterializer, KillSwitches}
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Keep, Sink, Source}
import com.sweetsoft.FsmSystem.{Add, StartTicker, StopTicker}

import scala.concurrent.duration._

object AddActor {

  def props: Props = Props(new AddActor)

}

final class AddActor extends Actor with ActorLogging {

  implicit val materilizer = ActorMaterializer()

  private val consumer: NotUsed => Unit = _ =>
    context.parent ! Add

  private val runnable = Source.tick(2.second, 2.second, NotUsed)
    .named("Ticker")
    .toMat(Sink.foreach(consumer))(Keep.both)

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case StartTicker =>

      runnable.run()
    case StopTicker =>

  }
}
```

When the Actor receives the message `StopTicker`, then I would like to stop the stream. And by `StartTicker`, then start the stream.

Calling the `run()` method, I would get the materialized value `Cancellabel` but it is impossible to access within the `StopTicker` scope.

What should I do?

Comment: save it in a variable

Comment: But it is not possible with `val` only `var`, right?

Comment: yes, using `var` is common in `Actors` (it's not real functional). Just make sure you never access it outside of message processing. Like don't close it, and to put it on a `Future`.

Comment: Really, or it is better to build an `Actor` with `FSM`?

Comment: I don't see how it is related. FSM has _state_, so, it is inherently mutable. All that DSL does is lets you hide changes to the state designator itself behind the API. I don't think it matters for anything in practice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [becode/unbecome](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/actors.html#become-unbecome) pattern:

```
final class AddActor extends Actor with ActorLogging {
    import context._

    implicit val materilizer: ActorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()

    private val consumer: NotUsed => Unit = _ =>
      self ! Add //send Add to self rather than directly to context.parent

    private val runnable = Source.tick(2.second, 2.second, NotUsed)
      .named("Ticker")
      .toMat(Sink.foreach(consumer))(Keep.both)

    override def preStart(): Unit = { //start runnable on actor start
      super.preStart()
      runnable.run()
    }

    val running: Receive = { //when running ignore new StartTicker but handle StopTicker and Add
      case StopTicker =>
        become(paused)

      case Add =>
        context.parent ! Add
    }

    val paused: Receive = { //handle just StartTicker
      case StartTicker =>
        become(running)
    }

    override def receive: Receive = paused //initial receive is paused

}
```